# Excel VBA copy/paste column from multiple sheets to one sheet in different Columns

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, copy

I have a workbook with approx 20 sheets, which are identical in format and setup. Only the sheet names differ (like "1010", "1020", "1030" and so on).
Now I would like to copy from every sheet Column D to a newly created sheet, however:

Column D from sheet "1010" needs to go to Column G in the newly created sheet.

Column D from sheet "1020" needs to go to Column H in the newly created sheet.

and so on.
I have manually created the following code for copy/paste Column D into the new sheet.

```
Sheets("1010").Select  
 Columns("D:D").Select  
 Application.CutCopyMode = False  
 Selection.Copy  
 Sheets("1000 (2)").Select  
 Range("G1").Select  
 ActiveSheet.Paste  

    Sheets("1020").Select  
Columns("D:D").Select  
Application.CutCopyMode = False  
Selection.Copy  
Sheets("1000 (2)").Select  
Range("H1").Select  
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Somehow I think this can go faster, although i have no idea how. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

This should do want you need:

```
Sub marine()
    Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "compilation"
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
        Sheets(i).Range("D:D").Copy Cells(1, 6 + i)
    Next i
End Sub
```